# hibernate insert to hsqldb with data exception: invalid datetime format

Tags: jpa, hsqldb

I am running a springboot project's test, I have a sql file before test as @Sql({"mysqlfile.sql"}):

```
insert into tableA( id, ..., changetime,...) values
('cdc1360e-390f-442b-9e61-c5659d3a56b4',...,'2022-01-01T15:00:00Z',...),
```

and the entity mapping to the sql has the same property with above sql value list

> ZonedDateTime changetime,

the test database is hsql and it will throw error like:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid datetime format
```

any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

SQL timestamp format does not include the letters T and Z. Try the following:

```
'2022-01-01 15:00:00'
```